# Use decorator with autofac for all implementation of interface

Tags: c#, .net, decorator, autofac

I have many implementations on interface IExecutor, implementation is resolved by incoming parameter type.
Autofac container is built like this:

```
builder.RegisterType<OtherExecutor>().Keyed<IExecutor>(typeof (OtherProduct));
builder.RegisterType<SomeExecutor>().Keyed<IExecutor>(typeof (SomeProduct));
```

resolving concrete executor:

```
var executorFactory = container.Resolve<IIndex<Type, IExecutor>>();
var executor = executorFactory[typeof (SomeProduct)];
```

How can I use decorator for all executors?

Full sample:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<OtherExecutor>().Keyed<IExecutor>(typeof (OtherProduct));
        builder.RegisterType<SomeExecutor>().Keyed<IExecutor>(typeof (SomeProduct));
        var container = builder.Build();

        var executorFactory = container.Resolve<IIndex<Type, IExecutor>>();
        var executor = executorFactory[typeof (SomeProduct)];
        executor.Execute(new SomeProduct());
        executor = executorFactory[typeof (OtherProduct)];
        executor.Execute(new OtherProduct());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

internal class SomeProduct { }

internal class OtherProduct { }

interface IExecutor
{
    void Execute(object obj);
}

class OtherExecutor : IExecutor
{
    public void Execute(object obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"OtherExecutor.Execute({obj.GetType()})");
    }
}

class SomeExecutor : IExecutor
{
    public void Execute(object obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"SomeExecutor.Execute({obj.GetType()})");
    }
}

class LoggerDecoratorExecutor : IExecutor
{
    private readonly IExecutor _innerExecutor;

    public LoggerDecoratorExecutor(IExecutor innerExecutor)
    {
        _innerExecutor = innerExecutor;
    }

    public void Execute(object obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Begin Execute");
        _innerExecutor.Execute(obj);
        Console.WriteLine("End Execute");
    }
}
```

Comment: see the [decorator](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/adapters-decorators.html#decorators) documentation

Comment: I have read this docs, but this sample works only for one service name, but I have many names (IIndex<Type, IExecutro> its like Abstract Factory)